# jquery expand element height to fill another

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, expand

I'm new to jquery plugins, with this code I want to expand the height of one or more elements to the height of another (normally the window object).
Please review the code to see if it's correct. Thanks.

```
(function( $ ) {
    $.fn.expandh = function(padre) {
        if(padre==undefined)padre=window;
        this.each(function(){
            $(this).height($(padre).height() - $(this).offset().top);
        });
    };
}( jQuery ));
```

[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/ddanone/fs5eoyy0/2/)

Comment: Is this code working?

Comment: yes, it's working for me at the moment.

Comment: Review service available on CR.

Comment: sorry, what means CR ??